# How can I get to the Sky dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've heard about another dimension in Minecraft, similar to the Nether and the End, but I don't know how to get there.

Does it exist? Is it possible to get there? If so, how?

Comment: Unrelated information: You might want to have a look at the biosphere mod. Which gives you a world generator that also creates a special kind of sky level.

Answer (score 10):

A currently-unfinished version of the [Sky dimension](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sky_Dimension) does exist within the game, but is inaccessible without the use of mods. While notch, the original creator of Minecraft, said it was "confirmed", it was put on indefinite hiatus until the Nether was made "more fun". It has not been mentioned at all in several months, and [there are no plans](https://twitter.com/jeb_/status/219758430276173824) for it to be implemented in vanilla Minecraft properly.

However, as I mentioned, there are many mods that can grant you access to it: for example [this one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1230914-125-sky-dimension-mod/) which causes the portal to the End to instead take you to the Sky dimension.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod called "The Aether"

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/495374-173-aether-collaboration-mod-v102-new-mobs-fixes-items-and-features/

Once again, it's a mod, so its nothing official. Still tho, i advice you to check it out.

Otherwise, there is no official Sky Dimennsion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the the sky dimension was supposedly going to be a "dream world" but Notch decided to make things "more interesting" by changing it to what we now know as The End. If you press <kbd>F3</kbd> and look at the numbers it will say "Sky". The End *is* the sky dimension.

Answer (score 0):

"The Overworld" is the common unofficial name for the dimension you spawn into.

From the nether, construct a portal, light it up and go through. You get a lit portal free of charge as you enter the nether; building a new one 128m (or 128 blocks) further away from the original portal will not get you back to where you left so be careful!

From the end, the portal to go back to the overworld will appear after the credits roll.

If all else fails, simply die. You'll respawn in the overworld - if at all (HC worlds need not apply)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which is about a separate dimension to the Nether and the End

Comment: @Gareth The question was about the Overworld when I started answering. If it was edited after I answered how would I know?

Answer (score 0):

I have the required class file to make it work, but all the links that had it are now gone. Create a .java file and put the following code inside:

```
public class rh extends xa {
    public void a() {
        this.b = (xv)new hd(kd.m, 0.5D, 0.0D);
        this.g = 1;
    }
  
    public cl b() {
        return (cl)new jd(this.a, this.a.s());
    }
  
    public float a(long l, float f) {
        return 0.0F;
    }
  
    public float[] a(float f, float f1) {
        return null;
    }
  
    public bt b(float f, float f1) {
        int i = 8421536;
        float f2 = in.b(f * 3.141593F * 2.0F) * 2.0F + 0.5F;
        if (f2 < 0.0F)
          f2 = 0.0F; 
        if (f2 > 1.0F)
          f2 = 1.0F; 
        float f3 = (i >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
        float f4 = (i >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
        float f5 = (i & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
        f3 *= f2 * 0.94F + 0.06F;
        f4 *= f2 * 0.94F + 0.06F;
        f5 *= f2 * 0.91F + 0.09F;
        return bt.b(f3, f4, f5);
    }
  
    public boolean c() {
        return false;
    }
  
    public float d() {
        return 8.0F;
    }
  
    public boolean a(int i, int j) {
        int k = this.a.a(i, j);
        if (k == 0)
        return false; 
        return (uu.m[k]).bA.c();
    }
}
```

compile it into a class file, call it rh.class, and put that into a beta 1.7 jar file. Then using multimc, create a beta 1.7 instance, import the custom jar, launch it, and all world should generate floating islands.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to go there or it is not added but i think it's the dream land and you don't have to mod because there is a chance that you can go there

Comment: You seem to have accidentaly slip your answer into two. I edited the other answer into this one. You should propably delete the other one.

Answer (score -1):

The Sky dimension is not that simple to get to; you need to make a 5 by 5 portal - like the one for the Nether - but instead use gold for the corners and the middles, and iron for the rest.
I am not sure if you have to ignite it, but if it does not work, ignite it.
You'll have to have the 1.15 version of Minecraft, as old consoles don't have it. You *can* get the patch, but need to mod your console.

Let me give an idea of the Sky dimension: it is a world with a lot of flying islands, and there is a big red Dragon, which slowly burns up the islands. When it gets tired you can try to kill it.

Answer (score -2):

There is the Aether, a dimension directly above the overworld. There is also the dream world (hidden in minecraft source/main code), an incomplete dimension accessible through the use of a Dream Bed. There is other incomplete stuff as well. To help you, there is a mod for it. But you don't need it. Since it's hidden in the minecraft codes, the supplies for it can only be found by its number.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct, particular the end part about not needing a mod to access. even in the pocket edition through creative mode you can get items which you cannot craft/find/collect as drops and there is no "Dream Bed" when you search every item in Vanilla Minecraft. you need to add in either a command to get this "Dream Bed" in game to validate your claims otherwise a link to the mod you refer will help people determine if said mod is accessing already existence source code or adding it in itself as new content

Comment: Also, on the [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Removed_features#Horse_saddle) i can find entries on removed content but no entries of a "Dream Bed" while the entry on the [Sky Dimension](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sky_Dimension) has Notch imply you use a normal bed

Comment: I told you its hidden in the codes.If you try to get it by its number i think it will work

Comment: Xbox one edition dosn't allow you.

Comment: *"To help you, there is a mod for it. But you don't need it. Since it's hidden in the minecraft codes"* this implies you can get it in  Vanilla Minecraft (no modification) which means that if i can't find it in creative mode then the only other way to get it is with a command which you have not provided. also as i point out the wiki has no entries on this item despite it having entries on items which have been removed so unless you provide evidence i can only assume this is incorrect as it's you word against a wiki that's been accurately maintained

Comment: Like I saed,xbox one edition doesn't use ccodes.I can do nothing about that.

Answer (score -2):

The sky dimension is not that simply to make but you need to make a 5 by 5 portal like the nether but instead use gold for the corners and the middles and iron for the rest i am not sure if you have to ignite it but if it does not work ignite it  but you have to have the 1.15 version of Minecraft but old consoles don't have it but u can get the patch but you need to mod your console

Let me explain the sky dimension it is a world with a lot of islands flying island and there is a big red Dragon which slowly burns up the islands when it gets tired you can try to kill it you have to kill the dragon to get back

Comment: Try it in creative and read about 1.15

Comment: You already answered this.  Please edit your answer instead of posting a new one.